# iPad mini retina doesn't boot

Tags: startup, ios

My iPad shows the Apple logo, and then it turns off.

I tried reinstalling iOS with iTunes (update) and it returned error 27?

Any ideas of what to do?

Comment: Restoring to factory settings did work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you researched error 27: https://www.google.com/search?q=itunes+update+error+27&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari
It appears to be a hardware problem, so you may need to go to the Apple Store.